Completion of a positive measure
Let $(X,\mathcal{M}, \mu)$ a measurable space, $\mu:\mathcal{M}\to [0,+\infty]$ a positive measure.
We define $$\mathcal{M}_\mu=\{E\subseteq X : \exists A,B\in\mathcal{M},\hspace{3pt} A\subseteq E\subseteq B, \hspace{3pt} \mu(B\setminus A)=0\}$$
We can prove that $\mathcal{M}_\mu$ is a sigma algebra on $X$. So, we can define the following positive measure on it:
$$\mu^\ast:\mathcal{M}_\mu \to[0,+\infty], \hspace{5pt} \mu^\ast(E)=\mu(A), \hspace{7pt} \forall E\in \mathcal{M}_\mu$$
called completion of $\mu$.
Therefore, if $\mathcal{M}$ is a sigma algebra on $X$, a measure $\mu:\mathcal{M}\to [0,+\infty]$ is said complete iff $\ \mathcal{M}=\mathcal{M}_\mu$. Equivalently, $\mu$ is complete if and only if for all $E\subseteq X$ for which $\exists N\in\mathcal{M}$ such that $E\subseteq N$ with $\mu(N)=0$, we have $E\in \mathcal{M}$.
Now, my teacher show that $\mu^\ast$ is complete using the definition.
Let $E\subseteq N$ with $N\in \mathcal{M}_\mu$, $\mu^\ast(N)=0$.
By definition, exists $A,B\in \mathcal{M}$ with $A\subseteq N \subseteq B, \hspace{3pt} \mu(B\setminus A)=0$ and $\mu(A)=\mu^\ast(N)=0$.
Then, $\mu(B)=0$.
Therefore, $\emptyset\subseteq E\subseteq N\subseteq B$ with $\mu(B\setminus \emptyset)=\mu(B)=0$ implies $E\in \mathcal{M}_\mu$.
I can't understand why the two definition are equivalent and why $\mu(B)=0$ in the proof. Maybe there's something wrong written in the proof.
Thanks to whoever want to help me.
